# How to add external remote JS source to Gravity Forms?

Tags: jquery, javascript, plugin-gravity-forms

I would like to add an external javascript source to my Gravity Form.
Like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=true_or_false"></script>
```

How to do this? I don't get how can I do this with the function: wp_enqueue_script

Then after adding this external/remote JS source, I would like use a custom JS with http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Gform_register_init_scripts
such as this line:

```
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(inputAddress);
```

But this won't work unless I have the external JS source added...Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for [`gform_enqueue_scripts`](http://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/page/Gform_enqueue_scripts) which is simply a Gravity Forms specific version of the `wp_enqueue_scripts` hook. Either hook uses the [`wp_enqueue_script()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) function.

That function can take a local script—usually using `get_template_directory_uri()` (theme), `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` child theme), or `plugins_url()` (plugin) to reference the file location—or an external location like what you're trying to do. You'd probably load both the external JS and your custom file on that same hook with two calls to `wp_enqueue_script()` with your custom file listing the external file as a dependency in the `$deps` arg.

What goes in that custom sheet is out of scope of this forum as it's plugin specific, but this should get you going.